# Command line to consider common values in only in specific column

Tags: linux, awk, terminal, command-line-arguments, comm

I am looking for an simple command line to help me with the following task.

I have two files and I would like to print the lines for which they have a value in Col2 in common.

For instance File1 is similar to the following 3-column tab separated example

File1

```
cat big 24
cat small   13
cat red 63
```

File2

```
dog big 34
chicken plays   39
fish    red 294
```

desired output

```
big
red
```

I have tried commands using the `comm`syntax: `comm /path/to/file1/ /path/to/file2`
However, it does not output me anything because the values in Col1 and Col3 will very rarely be in common.
Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can be solved, maybe `awk` is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the man page of `comm`, you will see it works with `sorted` files. But awk is flexible, you can control what you want:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=1;next}a[$2]{print $2}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a single pass with `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$2 == $5 { print $2 }'
```

Output:

```
big
red
```

Comment: this is risky.. think about the lines in file2 are `red then big`

Comment: @Kent: Sure, this assumes that line `n` in `file1` should be compared to line `n` in `file2`. This is how I understood the question.